# Test of IPv6 and IPv4 using D-ITG

Tags: ipv6

recently i am working on o project to test the performacne of IPv6.

I am not so familiar with this subject and my supervisior advised me to use D-ITG to test.

I have two laptops (both have win7 ultimate and Ubuntu 11.10) at home. Ping is working in both systems on both laptops. But when i use D-ITG (2.8 rc1 or 2.7 beta2), i CAN NOT ITGSend or receive if either one of host is in linux. Anyone know why?

Is it possbile to test it in my lan with only fe80::xx address without a ipv6 router?

Answer (score 1):

you can try with the following format :

Itgsend -a (Destination IP address) -C (Packet per Second) -t (Duration) -c (Packet Size) -x (Destination folder to keep the log file)

example :

Itgsend -a fe80::1 -C 10000 -t 20000 -c 512 -x c:\result_log